# How to cache Mongodb Queries?

Tags: mongodb, python-2.7, caching

I am using mongodb 2.4.6 and python 2.7 .I have frequent executing queries.Is it possible to save the frequent qaueries results in cache.?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes but you will need to make one, how about memcached or redis?

However as a pre-cautionary note, MongoDB does have its recently used data cached to RAM by the OS already so unless you are doing some really resource intensive aggregation query or you are using the results outside of your working set window you might not actually find that it increases performance all that much.

Comment: Actually i am working on multiple databases with same queries,and my database is going to be huge so how can i do it..?

Comment: @Shiva I would cache to memcached

Comment: I have referred some memcached docs,but i didnt understand.Can you please give me a simple code to cache a qurey